# C++: Time complexity of using STL's sort in order to sort a 2d array of integers on different columns

Tags: c++, performance, stl, sorting, time-complexity

let's say we have the following 2d array of integers:

```
1 3 3 1
1 0 2 2
2 0 3 1
1 1 1 0
2 1 1 3
```

I was trying to create an implementation where the user could give as input the array itself and a string. An example of a string in the above example would be `03` which would mean that the user wants to sort the array based on the first and the fourth column.

So in this case the result of the sorting would be the following:

```
1 1 1 0
1 3 3 1
1 0 2 2
2 0 3 1
2 1 1 3
```

I didn't know a lot about the compare functions that are being used inside the STL's `sort` function, however after searching I created the following simple implementation:

I created a class called `Comparator.h`

```
   class Comparator{

     private:
      std::string attr;

     public:
      Comparator(std::string attr) { this->attr = attr; }

      bool operator()(const int* first, const int* second){
       std::vector<int> left;
       std::vector<int> right;
       size_t i;
       for(i=0;i<attr.size();i++){
                left.push_back(first[attr.at(i) - '0']);
                right.push_back(second[attr.at(i) - '0']);
        }
        for(i=0;i<left.size();i++){
                if(left[i] < right[i]) return true;
                else if(left[i] > right[i]) return false;
        }
        return false;
      }

     };
```

I need to know the information inside the string so I need to have a class where this string is a private variable. Inside the `operator` I would have two parameters `first` and `second`, each of which will refer to a row. Now having this information I create a `left` and a `right` vector where in the `left` vector I have only the numbers of the `first` row that are important to the sorting and are specified by the string variable and in the `right` vector I have only the numbers of the `second` row that are important to the sorting and are specified by the string variable.

Then I do the needed comparisons and return true or false. The user can use this class by calling this function inside the `Sorting.cpp` class:

```
void Sorting::applySort(int **data, std::string attr, int amountOfRows){

  std::sort(data, data+amountOfRows, Comparator(attr));

 }
```

Here is an example use:

```
int main(void){
    //create a data[][] variable and fill it with integers
    Sorting sort;

sort.applySort(data, "03", number_of_rows);
}
```

I have two questions:

**First question**

Can my implementation get better? I use extra variables like the `left` and `right` vectors, and then I have some for loops which brings some extra costing to the sorting operation.

**Second question**

Due to the extra cost, how much worse does the time complexity of the sorting become? I know that STL's `sort` is `O(n*logn)` where `n` is the number of integers that you want to sort. Here `n` has a different meaning, `n` is the number of rows and each row can have up to `m` integers which in turn can be found inside the `Comparator` class by overriding the `operator` function and using extra variables(the vectors) and for loops.

Because I'm not sure how exactly is STL's `sort` implemented I can only make some estimates.
   My initial estimate would be `O(n*m*log(n))` where `m` is the number of columns that are important to the sorting however I'm not 100% certain about it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may want to use a tuple instead of a string to decide which columns to use?

Comment: There is no need to copy the data per key that I can see. Is it your intention to only support ten distinct sort-columns in the array? I.e. the string supports single-digit characters 0-9 for id'ing sort columns. If you need column support beyond that then this algorithm is limited.

Comment: Alex, I didn't know about tuples, I will look for them.

WhozCraig, I'm interested only in having the numbers sorted correctly, I'm not sure about strict ordering, for example can you think of some case where the result would be wrong? I haven't tried my implementation on many cases so there might be some that I haven't thought of. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: since the size of the tuple is part of the type, I don't think they help much here. As I understand it, the number of columns participating in the comparison is not determined until runtime.

Comment: @ksm001 Looking at your loop, you actually have it right. you continue on equality, so I stand corrected. The rest still applies, but that looks correct (decide on inequality, continue otherwise, if I read it right). So long as it returns false if it reaches the end and still has not detected an inequality for decision, it should be fine. Lose the copying, and translate your indexes at construct time of your comparator, and I think your performance will be *much* better.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [code review](http://coderevuew.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I wasn't aware of this website, thank you for the information. Btw all the answers were great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly improve your comparator. There's no need to copy the columns and then compare them. Instead of the two `push_back` calls, just compare the values and either return true, return false, or continue the loop according to whether they're less, greater, or equal.

The relevant part of the complexity of `sort` is `O(n * log n)` comparisons (in C++11. C++03 doesn't give quite such a good guarantee), where `n` is the number of elements being sorted. So provided your comparator is `O(m)`, your estimate is OK to sort the `n` rows. Since `attr.size() <= m`, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

First question: you don't need left and rigth - you add elements one by one and then iterate over the vectors in the same order. So instead of pushing values to vectors and then iterating over them, simply use the values as you generate them in the first cycle like so:

```
    for(i=0;i<attr.size();i++){
            int left = first[attr.at(i) - '0'];
            int right = second[attr.at(i) - '0'];
            if(left < right) return true;
            else if(left > right) return false;
    }
```

Second question: can the time **complexity** be improved? Not with sorting algorithm that uses direct comparison. On the other had the problem you solve here is somewhat similar to [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort). And so I believe you should be able to do the sorting in O(n*m) where m is the number of sorting criteria.

Answer (score 1):

1) Firstly to start off you should convert the string into an integer array in the constructor. With validation of values being less than the number of columns.

(You could also have another constructor that takes an integer array as a parameter.
A slight enhancement is to allow negative values to indicate that the order of the sort is reversed for that column. In this case the values would be  -N..-1 , 1..N)

2) There is no need for the intermediate left, right arrays.